# Testing series for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}-1}{n(\sqrt n+1)}$$

I have tried comparing with the limit comparison test to a $p$-series. But the limit is hard to evaluate. Any suggestions to prove convergence?

Comment: If you want to do it formally, note that the $n$-th term is $\lt \frac{n^{1/3}}{n^{3/2}}$, which is $\frac{1}{n^{7/6}}$. Or (more generally useful, but a bit harder here) do a limit comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^{7/6}}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:$$\frac {\sqrt [3] {n}-1}{n(\sqrt n+1)}\sim_{\infty}\frac {\sqrt [3] {n}}{\sqrt n\cdot n}\sim_{\infty}\frac {1}{n^{\frac {7}{2}}}$$ that converges

Comment: SOrry I made a mistake .. it is cube root not 3 X root n

Comment: It's ok ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: What does $\sim _{\infty}$ mean? Didn't you mean $\frac {\sqrt [3] {n}}{\sqrt n\cdot n} = \frac {1}{n^{\frac {7}{2}}}$?

Comment: @AjmalW the initial series for $n$ very big has the same behaviour of final series

Comment: How did you find the other p series to compare it with. Could you go through the steps?

Comment: To see that a series converges or diverges usually it is compared with a harmonic series. You have to show that for $n$ very big a series has the same behaviour of an harmonic series

Answer (score 0):

Let $N = n^{1/6}$, then we have $$\frac{\sqrt[3]{n}-1}{n(\sqrt n+1)} = \frac {N^2 - 1} {N^6 (N^3 + 1)} = \frac {N + 1} {N^6 (N^2 + N + 1)} < \frac {1} {N^7} = \frac {1} {n^{7/6}},$$ hence $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt[3]{n}-1}{n(\sqrt n+1)} < \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {1} {n^{7/6}} = \zeta (\frac {7} {6}) = 6.589\cdots$$